# Adding collation for First Nations language

Tags: sql-server

My team is trying to find a way to incorporate support for First Nation languages in some of our applications. The web based forms accept the information correctly but it would appear that once it's committed to the database, certain character are replaced with questions marks.

We are using SQL server 2022 with the default collations set to: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

I'm currently just trying to alter a single column for testing:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.LangTest 
ALTER COLUMN LangAfter VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
```

Here are few examples of the characters it needs to support:

səlilwətaɬ
ƛ̓éxətəm
Tla-hut-um
Tsleil-Waututh

Comment: Why not use an `nvarchar`?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is between the application and sql server. what method do you use to insert the data?

Comment: The OP is almost certainly passing their value as a `varchar` to the database, @siggemannen . For string literals and variables the **database** collation is used, not the column it *might* be end up being stored in. The value the OP has as a `varchar` collated in `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` will be `'s?lilw?ta? ??éx?t?m Tla-hut-um Tsleil-Waututh'` and then that value will be inserted into their UTF-8 collated column. They *need* to pass an `nvarchar` value, use UTF-8 the whole way, or (likely best) just use an `nvarchar` the whole way.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. There are multiple applications (some hosted) that need to support this and I was just looking to see if there were commonalities in how data was stored that might help us out. We are actually going to go with  professional services due to the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The primary database I was concerned with does use varchar. I created a test database and was experimenting with changing columns. When I switched to database collation and used nvarchar it worked. As mentioned in my comment, we use several different applications and databases and will be using a service specialist for our project now.